# fetch firebase analytics events data

Tags: angular, firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have a hybrid app that is logging data in firebase. I would like to put the events data like first start, retention active users which comes out of the box, in my web application dashboard.

pushing bundles and reading the data from the new database tables are fine, but the thing which I am trying to read from firebase analytics is active users' data and others.

I could do that with bigquery although I am not sure how to integrate that with the web application I have in angular.

I do not see any method in the firebase analytics library.

I am currently trying to read it through google APIs. although creating a google auth is another challenge.

Any pointers on what should be the right way to go about reading the firebase analytics app events data from another web application.

Comment: I also need to read firebase analytics app events data from another web application. Did you solve this? Could you share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect it with kodular perhaps, so you can test it. When you do this, make sure you are on real time (inside fire base, since there are two options for this).